# handle overfitting in unbalanced datasets

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have an unbalanced dataset (only 0.06% of data is labeled 1 and the rest are labeled 0). As I researched, I had to resample the data, so I used `imblearn` package to `randomUnserSample` my dataset. Then I used a `Keras Sequential` to create a neural network. While training, `F1Score` increases to around 75% (1000th epoch result is: loss: 0.5691 - acc: 0.7543 - f1_m: 0.7525 - precision_m: 0.7582 - recall_m: 0.7472), but on test set, the result is disappointing (loss: 55.35181%, acc: 79.25248%, f1_m: 0.39789%, precision_m: 0.23259%, recall_m: 1.54982%).

What I assume is that on train set, because the number of 1s and 0s are the same and therefore class_wights are both set to 1, so the network is not costing much for wrong predictions of 1s.

I have used some techniques like reducing the number of layers, reducing number of neurons, using regularization and dropouts, but the test set `f1Score` is never more than 0.5%. What should I do. Thanks

my neural network:

```
def neural_network(X, y, epochs_count=3, handle_overfit=False):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=len(X_test.columns), activation='relu'))
    if (handle_overfit):
        model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.5))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.1)))
    if (handle_overfit):
        model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.1))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    # compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['acc', f1_m, precision_m, recall_m])

#     change weights of the classes '0' and '1' and set weights automatically
    class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', [0, 1], y)
    print("---------------------- \n chosen class_wieghts are: ", class_weights, " \n ---------------------")

    # Fit the model
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=epochs_count, batch_size=512, class_weight=class_weights)

    return model
```

defining train and test set:

```
vtrain_set, test_set = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.35, random_state=0)

X_train = train_set[['..... some columns ....']]
y_train = train_set[['success']]

print('Initial dataset shape: ', X_train.shape)
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42)
X_undersampled, y_undersampled = rus.fit_sample(X_train, y_train) 
print('undersampled dataset shape: ', X_undersampled.shape)
```

and result is:

```
Initial dataset shape:  (1625843, 11)
undersampled dataset shape:  (1970, 11)
```

and finally the neural network calling:

```
print (X_undersampled.shape, y_undersampled.shape)
print (X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

model = neural_network(X_undersampled, y_undersampled, 1000, handle_overfit=True)

# evaluate the model
print("\n---------------\nEvaluated on test set:")

scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
for i in range(len(model.metrics_names)):
    print("%s: %.5f%%" % (model.metrics_names[i], scores[i]*100))
```

and result is:

```
(1970, 11) (1970,)
(875454, 11) (875454, 1)
---------------------- 
 chosen class_wieghts are:  [1. 1.]  
 ---------------------
Epoch 1/1000
1970/1970 [==============================] - 4s 2ms/step - loss: 4.5034 - acc: 0.5147 - f1_m: 0.3703 - precision_m: 0.5291 - recall_m: 0.2859

.
.
.
.
Epoch 999/1000
1970/1970 [==============================] - 0s 6us/step - loss: 0.5705 - acc: 0.7538 - f1_m: 0.7471 - precision_m: 0.7668 - recall_m: 0.7296
Epoch 1000/1000
1970/1970 [==============================] - 0s 6us/step - loss: 0.5691 - acc: 0.7543 - f1_m: 0.7525 - precision_m: 0.7582 - recall_m: 0.7472

---------------
Evaluated on test set:
875454/875454 [==============================] - 49s 56us/step
loss: 55.35181%
acc: 79.25248%
f1_m: 0.39789%
precision_m: 0.23259%
recall_m: 1.54982%
```

Comment: What about different random initializers (ex. Xavier, He, Glorot, LeCun) for the layers? Maybe this is a symmetry breaking problem.

Comment: See [this link](https://keras.io/initializers/) for some initializer examples. Since the bias initializer vector is by default zeroes you might have a symmetry problem.